# PostgreSQL: Bloating of pg_catalog.pg_attribute table

Tags: postgresql

I have a DB that has a heavy transactional load (around 2-3 million transaction inserts per day) and each transaction insert creates several temp tables before committing the transaction.

In the process, pg_attribute table has got bloated. The number of rows in the table is less than 10k as of now, but the size is still 10GB.

I ran FULL VACUUM several times on this table, but it didn't help. Even restarted the DB and done FULL VACUUM again.

What are my options?

[image: pg_attribute is occupying 10GB]

**Update**

```
postgres=# VACUUM (VERBOSE) pg_catalog.pg_attribute;
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_attribute"
INFO:  "pg_attribute": found 0 removable, 25 nonremovable row versions in 1 out of 49 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 650634809
There were 30 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 25 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
VACUUM
postgres=#

SELECT schemaname, relname, n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, last_autovacuum
FROM pg_stat_all_tables
ORDER BY n_dead_tup
    / (n_live_tup
       * current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor')::float8
          + current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_threshold')::float8)
     DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

[image: This is the result of my above query]

Answer (score 1):

Something is holding the tuples back.  Since restarting the database didn't fix the problem, it must be something durable.  To my knowledge, that would be either a prepared transaction, or a logical replication slot.  So look in the  pg_prepared_xacts and pg_replication_slots views.

Comment: It could also be a standby with a long running transaction and `hot_standby_feedback = on`.

Comment: I had `hot_standby_feedback = off` commented. So not sure if it was on, now I uncommented it. Also checked, `pg_prepared_xacts` and `pg_replication_slots`. Nothing there as well. I am desperate to clean it up :-)

Comment: hot_standby_feedback needs to be turned off on the replica, not on the master.

Comment: I have added an Update to the original post. There are no dead rows as per the output of Vacuum.  What am I still missing here?